# How can I get from the object list of all connected objects with him (SilverLight)

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

Can someone help me to resolve question? I knew it should be someting like this:

```
  Canvas.Where(c => c.ChildItem == data || c.ParentItem == data);
```

Comment: Provide more details regarding what is `data` and how `object list` is declared

Comment: @sll, Can I send you this part of the code on your mail?

Comment: I believe the right way is to post mostly related code snippets in the question

Comment: post it here. if it's a subject of company property, then change the names and simplify the example.

Comment: @sll data is object that I can get: public void Element_MouseMove(object data, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e )

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you need to look for a way of getting list of descendants and ancestors for `FrameworkElement` that is under Mouse? Or just previous and next item in `VisualTreeHelper` hierarchy?